# ReactJs unable to find Ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

My target: to find ref of label and colorize it. Code used:

```
colorizeLabel(){
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.amountLabel).color('#ffffff');
}

<label itemRef="amountLabel">Choose Amount:</label>
```

which produce: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'color' of null`

It looks like it is unable to find ref. Do I miss anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify ref in element

`<label ref="amountLabel">Choose Amount:</label>`

However it is [advised](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-string-attribute) to use `ref` as below

`<label ref={(ref) => this.myLabel = ref} />`

and you can access label as `this.myLabel`

Comment: this produce ReactDOM.findDOMNode(...).color is not a function

Comment: you cannot modify color like that.. you need to use props/states to handle that